# Is it possible to attach two word file with each other?

Tags: ms-word, doc

Like in MS Excel one csv file may contain more than one sheet, Like this what I have to do is I want to keep all the theory in one word file and the programs in another word file. But I want to attach these both file with each other as a single DOC file.

Like a single DOC file contain theory as well as programs, which is open as two separate content/file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something close to what you want to do is the following:

In new Word Document Select your "View" Tab and then Select "Outline View".

Then Select "Show Document". The "Insert Button will now be visible.

You can now insert various documents in this document.

Unfortunately as far as I know this will have links into the original Documents which you can then open, edit and access from the new document.

Try it out and let me know!

Also, you can maybe try Microsoft One Note, I think this is probably what you looking for. See partial screen shot below for an idea.

[image]

Comment: Not Exactly @jean-pierre-oosthuizenn, It is only merging two doc files into one. Beside this I want attach a separate file which i can open only when i need.
Thanks for the Answer.

Comment: @ArpitShah It operates as you want though, you just need to collapse the the documents you don not want to see. Otherwise what you can try is Microsoft One Note in there you can insert what ever files you want and then it it stored together.